# Error while conan install : while executing system_requirements(): Command 'sudo apt-get update' failed

Tags: cmake, sudo, conan

I'm trying to run the following command:

`conan install .. --build=missing && cmake .. -G "Unix Makefiles" && cmake -build`

What I'm interested in is the conan install part
Everything works fine until the end, it starts sudo apt-get install and after a few seconds of the commands running I got this error:

> portaudio/19.7.0@bincrafters/stable: ERROR: while executing system_requirements(): Command 'sudo apt-get update' failed
> ERROR: Error in system requirements

And this is my conanfile.txt

```
[requires]
opus/1.3.1
asio/1.24.0
sqlite3/3.40.1
sqlite_orm/1.8.1
qt/5.15.8
libalsa/1.2.7.2
portaudio/19.7.0@bincrafters/stable

[generators]
cmake
```

I tried different version of conan and the one who suits what I need is 1.57
I deleted my ./conan folder and re-installed it and add sysrequires_mode = enabled in my conan.conf

Comment: The ``bincrafters`` recipes might be no longer maintained, I'd recommend using recipes from ConanCenter . I see that ``portaudio`` specific package is not in ConanCenter, but trying to contribute it there might be a better way. Otherwise, I think you need to report to the ``bincrafters`` Github repository.

Comment: They are, it is a requirements that I use bincrafters and the issue doesn't seem to come from that

Comment: It is trying to install libjack-dev. Can you install that package manually? I.e. run `sudo apt install libjack-dev`? Do you need the libjack functionality? Which Linux distribution are you on?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I had to install libjack-dev after having resolved my issue, now it works fine !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I finally found the answer
When I made a `sudo apt update` I got this error

> E: The http://ppa.launchpad.net/snaipewastaken/ppa/ubuntu focal
> Release repository does not have a Release file.

So I went to "software and update" on Ubuntu, I found the said focal and deactivated it

Now it works fine, although I had to install libjack-dev afterwards